# Difference between printf %.3f and bc rounding behavior

Tags: bash, printf, bc

Ok so this is a hackerrank problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---arithmetic-operations). Basically, input is an arithmetic expression and I'm supposed to print out formatted answer (3 decimal places). I tried this at first

```
read exp
echo "scale = 3; $exp" | bc -l
```

It passed several tests but not the first one.

`5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7` The answer is `17.929` but my code prints out `17.928`. I tried this code instead

```
read exp  
printf "%.3f\n" `echo $exp | bc -l`
```

Note: the echo part should be in backticks but I put ' ' to not confuse with block quotes. All tests passed. So what's the difference?

Comment: Backticks are only appropriate for code formatting less than a line -- for multiline segments, use indentation for code formatting (which is what the javascript editor will do for you if you click the code button).

Comment: ...alternately, use `$(...)` instead of `\`...\`` anyhow -- it's the modern POSIX syntax, and less confusing to nest.

Comment: ....also -- `echo "$exp" | bc -l`, not `echo $exp | bc -l`; if your expression contained spaces around the `*`, you'd have very surprising behavior without the quotes (and even without the spaces, you'd have surprising behavior if your shell had the `nullglob` option enabled).

Comment: a little more verbose :) ```read a; echo "scale=4; $a" | bc -l | xargs -I {} printf '%.*f\n' 3 {}```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that the two differ is that `bc` always cuts off the numbers instead of rounding them. I. e. `echo "scale = 3 ; 8/9" | bc` produces 0.888 instead of the correctly rounded 0.889.

Your test case evaluates to 17.928571429, which is rounded to 17.929 with your `printf` approach, but cut off to 17.928 with the `bc` approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is `scale = 3;` part. For example, if you use

```
      printf "%.3f\n" ` echo  "scale = 3 ; $exp " | bc -l`
```

You will get 17.928 again. So the answer is you need to set scale at least to 4 and then print it in three digit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is *rounding* and/or *significant digits* returned by `bc`. When you use `echo` with `scale=3` you are relying on `bc` to return only 3 digits. When you tell `printf` to output only *3 decimal places* (using the format `%.3f`), you are relying on `printf` to determine which digits. Essentially, the difference is in the rounding done by `bc` utilizing `scale=3` and that done by `printf` with the double `%.3f` conversion.

Comment: I hope I'm not being presumptuous or heavy-handed with the edit.

Comment: Nope -- looks perfect. Take all the editorial liberty you need :)

Answer (score 0):

```
v=$(sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g')
(echo "scale=4"; echo $v) | bc | xargs printf '%.3f'
```

The above reads the integer from stdin, removes the blank lines, pipes it to bc to perform the calculation with 4 digits precision, then formats it with correct rounding to 3 digits with the help of printf. My solution to the above mentioned HackerRank problem.